# How can I find whether a feature class has editor tracking set to database time instead of UTC?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class

I'm trying to publish a map service with about thirty layers in it. During the Service Editor Analyze step, it gave me a high-severity [error 00129](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/publish-map-services/00129-data-frame-has-layers-that-record-editor-tracking-dates-in-utc-and-database-time-zones.htm):

> Services cannot include data where Editor Tracking is enabled and set to record dates in database time. Services can include data where Editor Tracking is enabled and set to record dates in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Suggest solutions (from Esri) include removing the layers, disabling Editor Tracking for the datasets, or turning off field visibility for editor tracking date fields. I'd be happy to do that, but would love to know *which* layer is causing my problem -- the error only says the *data frame has layers*, not specific to a single layer.

Is there a quick way to find what layers have editor tracking set to database times instead of UTC? (ArcPy scripts are an option, even if I need to run it on all the feature classes in the SDE -- I just don't know what command or function would check this characteristic!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [Describe function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/editor-tracking-properties.htm):

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(your_fc)
if desc.editorTrackingEnabled and not desc.isTimeInUTC:
   print 'you need to switch this to UTC to publish!'
```

Comment: YES. I _knew_ Python could save the day!